# How to require a client certificate to a web application in IIS?

Tags: ssl, iis, digital-certificate

I have created an asp.net web application and deployed it in IIS10. The design of the application is to require a client certificate for each user which will be provided by us. For testing purposes I created a self-signed certificate using the makecert.exe and followed the instructions at https://blog.jayway.com/2014/10/27/configure-iis-to-use-your-self-signed-certificates-with-your-application/. I added the certificate in the MMC Personal Certificates.

I also configured the iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication in the IIS Configuration Editor using the one-to-one mapping approach. When I tested it on the browser, at first it asked for a digital certificate (which is correct), but when I clicked the certificate I added on the bindings it returns an error "Your client certificate is either not trusted or is invalid."

What should be the problem here since the installed client certificate is already added in the IIS one to one mapping configuration? Do I need additional configuration in the IIS?

Comment: You also need to add the self-signed certificate to the Trusted Certificate Authorities store of machine account on the IIS machine.

Comment: Yes I already did that but it still prompts me that the client certificate is invalid.

Comment: Then you cannot only link to a post and ask others to guess what happened. Post more information about what you had done (screen shots) and so on, or this question won’t be answered.